# Number of generator sets in a dihedral group.

Tags: group-theory

need find number of such pairs of elements $g, h\in D_n.$

Do I need to manually find such pairs?

At least, if there is a way to not consider the group table?

I feel this question should be generic for $D_n$. Hence, need not consider table, but not currently able to think otherwise.

Ideally, some co-prime indexes should be chosen, but cannot say more.

Let, $n=6,$ Cayley table for $D_{2n=12}$ is having $n=6$ rotations, and $n=6$ reflections.

All pairs of the form $S_iR_i$ yield only $R_0$.
$$1> R_1S_1= S_2, S_2S_2= R_0$$
$$1> R_3S_3= S_0, S_0S_0= R_0$$
$$2> R_2S_2= S_4, S_4S_4= R_0$$

So, need $i\neq j$.

But, $R_5S_1$ fails too, as gives $S_0$, which on concatenation  with itself yields $R_0$.

Taking two reflections also doesn't help in getting any generator too, as loop occurs after some step.

Group table:

$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}  & R_0 & R_1 &R_2 & R_3& R_4 &R_5& S_0 & S_1 &S_2 & S_3& S_4 &S_5
 \\ \hline 
R_0 & R_0 & R_1 &R_2 & R_3& R_4 &R_5&S_0 & S_1 & S_2 & S_3& S_4 &S_5\\ 
R_1 & R_1 &R_2 & R_3& R_4 &R_5 & R_0& S_1 & S_2 &S_3 & S_4 & S_5 &S_0\\ 
R_2 &R_2 & R_3& R_4 &R_5& R_0 & R_1 & S_2 & S_3 &S_4 & S_5& S_0 &S_1\\ 
R_3 & R_3& R_4 &R_5& R_0 & R_1 &R_2& S_3 & S_4 &S_5 & S_0& S_1 &S_2\\
R_4 & R_4 &R_5& R_0 & R_1 &R_2 & R_3&S_4 & S_5 &S_0 & S_1& S_2 &S_3\\ 
R_5 & R_5& R_0 & R_1 &R_2 & R_3& R_4& S_5 & S_0&S_1 & S_2& S_3 &S_4\\ 
S_0 & S_0 & S_5 &S_4 & S_3& S_2 & S_1& R_0 & S_5 &R_4 & R_3& R_2 &R_1\\ 
S_1 & S_1 & S_0 &S_5 &S_4 & S_3& S_2 & R_1 & R_0 & S_5 &R_4 & R_3& R_2 \\
S_2 & S_2 & S_1 &S_0 & S_5 &S_4 & S_3& R_2 & R_1 & R_0 & S_5 &R_4 & R_3\\ 
S_3 & S_3 & S_2 & S_1 &S_0 & S_5 &S_4& R_3 & R_2 & R_1 & R_0 & S_5 &R_4\\ 
S_4 & S_4 & S_3 & S_2 & S_1 &S_0 & S_5& R_4 & R_3 & R_2 & R_1 & R_0 & S_5 \\ 
S_5 & S_5 & S_4 & S_3 & S_2 & S_1 &S_0& R_5 &  R_4 & R_3 & R_2 & R_1 & R_0\\
 \end{array} $

*Edit* Any generator in dihedral groups cannot be purely reflection, or rotation.

It has to be a composition or 'word' : $R^aTR^bT$ = $R^{a-b}$, as $$TR^aT= R^b\implies
TR^aT= R^{-a}$$, as have an observed property in dihedral groups that:$R^aT = TR^{-a}$.

So, $R^aTR^bT = R^aR^{-b}TT= R^{a-b}$.

As <strike>$D_n$ is a cyclic group), so
this brings it back to totient functions, as only generator elements are those co-prime to $n$.</strike>
*Edit:
$D_n$ is not a cyclic group, it's subgroup $C_n$ is.*

Restriction #1: $R^{a-b}$ being a generator, so: $a-b$ must be relatively prime to $12$, as needed for a
generator in a cyclic group.

But, do we also need to impose another restriction (#2) that :$a, b$ to be co-prime to $12$?

Restriction 1:
Also, $12$ is not a prime number, so the possible values of $b-a =\{1,5,7,11\}$ :

a. $b-a= 1\implies b= a+1$, hence $a=0,1,2,...11$ and the corresponding values of $b= 1,2,3,...,12\}$.
$12$ values possible of $b$.

b. $b-a= 5\implies b= a+5$, hence $a=0,1,2,...7$ and the corresponding values of $b= 5,6,7,...,12\}$.
But, these values are already covered

c. $b-a= 7\implies b= a+7$, hence $a=0,1,2,...5$ and the corresponding values of $b= 7,...,12\}$.
But, these values are already covered

d. $b-a= 11\implies b= a+11$, hence $a=0,1$ and the corresponding values of $b= 11, 12\}$.
But, these values are already covered

The total choices are: $
= 12$.

Both restrictions 1,2:
The numbers relatively prime to $12$ are: $1,5,7,11$. So, got $4$ choices, for each of $a,b$.

a. $b-a= 1\implies b= a+1$, hence $a=0,4,6, 10$ and the corresponding values of values of $b= \{1,5, 7, 11\}$.

b. $b-a= 5\implies b= a+5$, hence $a=0,2,4$ and the corresponding values of $b= \{5,7,11\}$.
But, these values of $b$ are already covered.

c. $b-a= 7\implies b= a+7$, hence $a=0,4$ and the corresponding values of $b=\{ 7, 11\}$.
But, these values of $b$ are already covered.

d. $b-a= 11\implies b= a+11$, hence $a=0$ and the corresponding values of $b=\{ 11\}$.
But, these values of $b$ are already covered.

The total choices are: 4

By reverse orientation have double choices: $12*2=24, 8 $respectively.

but if had further restriction #3, that both $a, b$ are co-prime to $12$, then answer =$0$.
So, which of the three is correct answer?
Request vetting and help.

Comment: For generating pairs of $D_n$ see Theorem $1.1$ and Theorem $2.1$ in K. Conrad's [notes](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/dihedral2.pdf). So any nonabelian group generated by a pair $(x,y)$ with $x$ and $y$ of order $2$ is isomorphic to a dihedral group.

Comment: For the record, I tried to do it in my head and got it wrong first time. The generating pair consists either of one of $6$ reflections together with a generating rotation, making $12$ pairs, or a reflection together with another reflection such that the composite of the two is a generating rotation making another $12$ pairs. But of course I have counted each pair of generating reflections twice, so the answer is $18$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Request if it could an answer.

Comment: @DietrichBurde The paper states on page #1 : "The hypotheses $x^n = 1$ and $y^2 = 1$ do not mean $x$ has order $n$ and $y$ has order $2$, but only that their orders divide $n$ and divide $2$."

But, cann't this be better stated, for the part: "...only that their orders divide $n$ and divide $2$."
 as: $|x|=n, |y|=2$, so any element generated by $x^i, (i\bmod n)| n$. Similarly, for $y^j, (j\bmod 2)|2$.

Comment: @DerekHolt But, taking reflections' pair shouldn't consider ordering as irrelevant, unless all reflections commute with each other. Am not sure that it holds

Comment: @DerekHolt please list a few examples, as still not sure.

Comment: Sorry it's $36$: 12 (ref,rot), 12 (rot,ref), and 12 (ref,ref).

Comment: @DerekHolt please give a few examples, as myself unable to find even one generator. Without checking cannot confirm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to think of this is to think for any two $g,h$ you choose, do they generate the complete group or some strict subgroup? Otherwise they do generate the complete group.

- When I choose $g,h$ both to be rotations, do they generate the group? Why (not)?
- When I choose $h$ to be a reflection, which rotations can I choose for $g$ such that we generate the full group?
- When both $g$ and $h$ are reflections, do they always generate the complete group, or do they generate some subgroup $D_{2k}$ with $k<6$. What $g,h$ should you choose? (Note: When $g$ and $h$ are both reflections, the element $gh$ is a rotation. Then one is back at the previous point with a reflection and a rotation).

I think it is easiest to think of $D_{12}$ by drawing a hexagon and thinking of its symmetries rather than staring at a table of relations (Although both viewpoints do have their uses, depending on the problem you try to solve).